# Why data exchange between 2 web apps using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post CANNOT be trusted by each other, even when using HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, redirect, openid-connect, saml

Why data exchange between two web applications using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post CANNOT be trusted by each web application, even when using HTTPS?

**Note:**

I understand that data exchange using query parameters has inherent security **risks like CSRF, leaking of data via browser history and access logs**, and **auto-form-post has inherent CSRF security risk**. However, that is not the point of discussion here. Lets assume that we mitigated CSRF. The question at hand is, **"Why can't each web application trust the exchanged data, even with HTTPS?"**

**Use Case:**
Consider two web applications running on https://one.abc.com and https://two.xyz.com. They both desire to exchange data but cannot communicate directly.

**Detailed Flow:**
Upon visiting https://one.abc.com, a page displays a button. When clicked, it submits to https://one.abc.com, then redirects to https://two.xyz.com. On https://two.xyz.com, another button exists, which when clicked, submits to https://two.xyz.com and redirects to https://one.abc.com.

As everything occurs over HTTPS, all elements including URLs, query parameters, and headers are encrypted during redirection.

With this setup, data exchange between the two web applications can be achieved using query parameters or auto-form-post.

**However, why can't each web application trust the exchanged data, even with HTTPS?**

In simpler terms, during the first step, if `https://one.abc.com` sends data using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post to `https://two.xyz.com`, `https://two.xyz.com` cannot trust that the data indeed originated from `https://one.abc.com`, even when HTTPS is used.

Similarly, during the second step, if `https://two.xyz.com` sends data using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post to `https://one.abc.com`, `https://one.abc.com`  cannot trust that the data indeed originated from `https://one.abc.com`, even when HTTPS is used.

***The above technique is used in SAML, OIDC for SSO.***

**Please let me know if my following understanding is correct:**

In the described redirect flow from `one.abc.com` to `two.xyz.com` and back to `one.abc.com`, the TLS (Transport Layer Security) encryption is established separately between your browser and each server involved. Let's break down the flow:

**From `one.abc.com` to `two.xyz.com`:**

- When you click on the button on `one.abc.com`, your browser initiates a request to `one.abc.com` over HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).
- `one.abc.com` responds with a redirect response (HTTP 302 Found) instructing your browser to go to `two.xyz.com`.
- Your browser then initiates a new HTTPS request to `two.xyz.com`, establishing a separate TLS connection between your browser and `two.xyz.com`.

**From `two.xyz.com` back to `one.abc.com`:**

- When you click on the button on `two.xyz.com`, your browser initiates a request to `two.xyz.com` over HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).
- `two.xyz.com` responds with a redirect response (HTTP 302 Found) instructing your browser to go to `one.abc.com`.
- Your browser then initiates a new HTTPS request to `one.abc.com`, establishing a separate TLS connection between your browser and `one.abc.com`.

Each of these connections (from your browser to `two.xyz.com` and from your browser back to `one.abc.com`) is encrypted using TLS independently. The TLS encryption ensures the confidentiality and integrity of the communication between your browser and each server, protecting the data exchanged during the redirect flow.

However, there's no direct TLS connection established between `two.xyz.com` and `one.abc.com` during the redirect flow. Instead, the HTTPS connections are terminated and re-established separately at each server endpoint.

For this reason in SAML, IDP signs the `SAML assertion` and in OIDC, OIDC Provider signs `id_token`.

Comment: Your answer should be an answer (as you originally made it), not part of your question

Comment: @Nick I want experts to review my answer and let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: They will do that, if you post it as an answer. Otherwise it's more likely your question will be closed as non-reproducible. But actually, regardless of that, this question is probably better suited to [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com) since it's not really about programming

Comment: @Nick on https://serverfault.com/questions/1156403/why-data-exchange-using-redirection-via-query-params-auto-form-post-cannot-be-tr @ 
Steffen Ullrich commented me to delete the answer and put the answer in the question.

Comment: @Nick: IMHO if the question is "is my understanding correct" than "my understanding" should be part of the question, not posted as answer.

Comment: As already commented on https://serverfault.com/questions/1156403/why-data-exchange-using-redirection-via-query-params-auto-form-post-cannot-be-tr - this question is better asked at [security.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that's reasonable. I interpreted the question differently but on re-reading, I think your interpretation is correct. I think the wording could be better though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that two things would have to happen to make this a secure connection:

1. The browser would need to be using a client certificate that is
   trusted by both servers
2. Both of the servers would have to authenticate the identity of the browser based on the TLS client cert.

Without these two conditions (and maybe more?), there would be nothing to prevent the client from sniffing/intercepting the data flowing between the two servers

Comment: Thanks for the response @William Denton.  I have modified the question, to make the use case more clear. I understand that data exchange using query parameters has inherent security risks like CSRF, leaking of data via browser history and access logs, and auto-form-post has inherent CSRF security risk. However, that is not the point of discussion here. The question at hand is, "Why can't each web application trust the exchanged data, even with HTTPS?"